# How to find horizontal scrollview has to scrollable size of childs

Tags: android, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I'm using horizontal scroll view in my app. I have right arrow icon in the right corner of the scrollview. I need to make that arrow visible only when the scroll view has more childs to scroll.

Suppose if the scroll view has only one child and it doesn't need to scroll, i need to disable the arrow.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

If current position is the last position in your view just invisible the arrow view

Comment: Sorry, im not telling at the time of scrolling. At the time of loading the activity, if the scroll view has less number of childs need to disable the arrow